# How to use @Autowired in spring

Tags: java, spring, autowired

my spring.xml is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd

">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.service" />
    <context:annotation-config />

</beans>
```

and I have Test1 class

```
package com.mkyong.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component("test1")
public class Test1 {
public int i=1;
}
```

I have a App class

```
package com.mkyong.common;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.mkyong.service.Test1;

public class App 
{
    @Autowired
    Test1 test1;

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "spring.xml");
        App app=new App();

        System.out.println(app.test1);
    }

}
```

But I get the output as null.I can not Autowire it properly.Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you do this:

```
App app=new App();
```

It creates a new instance of App that is NOT managed by Spring, hence you wont have the autowired components.

You need to declare the App bean in the spring xml and then retrieve it using `context.getBean("beanName")`

E.g. in the Spring XML you can declare the bean something like this:

```
<bean id="app" class="com.mkyong.common.App" />
```

and then retrieve it back with `context.getBean("app")` then it will have the Autowired components.

Comment: Thanks dude. It works fine now. Also I learnt from your answer .Thanks again. By the way do u know why it is not allowed to accept an answer within 6 min?

Comment: @SanjayaLiyanage  Read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50703/219240):*The rationale is that if people are accepting answers within minutes or even seconds (no joke), they haven't even had time to properly evaluate or test the answer.*

Comment: It can be done without unnecessary `context.getBean("beanName")` lookup see my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to search for your bean using `context.getBean("beanName")`. This introduces
unnecessary dependency on Spring framework. That's not very clean.

It could be better to annotate your `App` class with `@Configurable` annotation.

```
...
@Configurable
public class App 
{
    @Autowired
    Test1 test1;
...
```

and add to your spring.xml one tag:

```
<context:spring-configured />
```

Thats all. Now you can create your `App` class as you wanted and autowiring will work.

```
...
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
App app=new App();
System.out.println(app.test1);
...
```

Note: you need spring-aspects, spring-aop, aspectjrt on your classpath.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks friend. It is really helpful. I could have accepted this answer if this was quick. Anyway here is my upvote for the perfect answer.

Comment: one computer it works but in another same project does print null System.out.println(app.test1); after I made the changes you asked.any ideas