# How to create dynamic beans which have only a constructor with args

Tags: spring

I have a bean with final field.

```
public class Foo {
   Service service;
   final String bar;
   public Foo(String bar){};
}
```

`service` is not final and has a setter. `bar` is final and can have many values. I cannot remove the `final` keyword. I try to create a spring factory that allows to create Foo's instances with injected service and dynamic bar value. `factory.create(bar)`. `Foo` beans are instanciated at runtime because `bar` value is not known and unbounded

I have try:

- `@Configuration`, but configuration does not allow parameters not managed by spring or dynamic parameter.
- Lookup method needs a no-arg constructor.

Any idea ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `ApplicationContext.getBean(String name, Object... args)` method. You can pass arguments to bean creation with `args` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, ApplicationContext.getBean seems the less invasive way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use constructor injection in the Application Context XML as one way to do this:

```
<bean name="foo" class="com.example.Foo">

   <constructor-arg index="0">Bar</constructor-arg>

</bean>
```

---

EDIT: Missed that, check out this question: [How to use @Autowired in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337881/how-to-use-autowired-in-spring/17337917#17337917)

The second answer (not by me)

It looks like you might be able to use `@Configurable` annotation here.

Comment: `Foo` beans are instanciated at runtime because `bar` value is not known and unbounded. XML bean definition cannot be an answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @Configurable is a bit invasive. It needs aspectj and weaving at runtime